# React Router v4 with Redux - dispatch is not passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

So, I've been trying to switch my app to React Router v4 (the api has changed quite a lot), and this is where I've reached:

**Router Setup**

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
   thunkMiddleware,
   createLogger
)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);

const RouterLayout = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={Login} path="/login" />
                <Route component={AccountDetails} path="/account/:id" />
            </Switch>
        </App>
    </Provider>
);

const routes = (
    <HashRouter>
        <RouterLayout />
    </HashRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("app-container"));
```

Now my problem is that for some reason I can't get the redux hooked to my components:

```
export class Login extends React.Component<any, any> {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        // this.props.dispatch is undefined 
        // I'm getting however router props: 
        // match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                This is the Login Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect((state: AppState): any => {
    return state;
})(Login);
```

It's interesting that the `App` component can connect and get access to `dispatch` without issues, but `Login` doesn't have it. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: How are you getting dispatch in App ? is it through react-redux connect?

Comment: @D-reaper Yeah, exactly the same way I'm trying to get `dispatch` in `Login` (same code).

Comment: You didn't use mapDispatchToProps function (the second argument in connect), how are you getting the dispatch?

Comment: @D-reaper not sure what to tell you, but it's the same code, I'm going to try to clean up the code in `App` (keep the relevant bits only) and post it for clarity. However it's the same code, I don't pass a second argument to `connect`.

Answer (score 3):

If `this.props.dispatch` is not available, then most likely your component is not connected to redux.

I think the problem here is that you are exporting Login twice, one as a react component and the other as a component connected to the redux store (with export default). In the file where RouterLayout exists, you probably import login with the curly brackets and thus the Login component here is the component that is not connected to the redux.

In addition, your createStore does not look right. It should look like the following:

```js
const createStoreWithMiddleware = (reducer) => {
  const middlewares = applyMiddleware(
     thunkMiddleware,
     createLogger
  );

  return createStore(
    reducer,
    middlewares
  );
}

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);
```

Comment: Definitely sounds likely. Default exports have bitten me similarly in the past. From [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> If you do not supply your own mapDispatchToProps function or object full of action creators, the default mapDispatchToProps implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

Comment: Thanks (+1), It turns out you're right, didn't notice the incorrect import. Anyway changing it to the `default` export clashes with the `typescript` definitions, and the app doesn't compile, anyway you can give me an example (or a link) of how it should be done correctly?

Comment: To clarify, this is what I'm getting after the change: `Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any>>`

Comment: Anyway, changed everything (threw couple of `any` here and there, fixed the `import`), got it to compile - still don't see `dispatch`, ideas?

Comment: So you used the `export default connect ...` and removed the import in `import class Login ...` right? If so, then dispatch should be available, unless perhaps store is not declared properly. I suggest you also fix the store like what I have put in my updated answer